# Copy & Paste using Right Alt & Right Ctrl in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make a single key in the keyboard do copy and another key to do paste

based on my notebook keyboard the keys that are hardly used and close to each other are Right Alt & Right Ctrl keys

I tried creating script to do that, but did not work

```
RCtrl::Send {Ctrl}V
```

and tried

```
RCtrl::Send {Ctrl down}V{Ctrl up}
```

still not working.

how can i get them to work??

Comment: Your second snippet works fine for me. Though, you could also condense it to `RCtrl::Send , ^v` (same effect).

Comment: do i need a comma ?

Comment: No, but I use it for consistency. Many commands require commas to separate parameters, but some are flexible (like `Send` and `MsgBox`).